# Eclipse C++ Remote Debug / GUI related debugging issues

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I finally succeed remote debugging from my windows machine to remote linux binary.

I can almost do everything except few things. Forexample I can't insert break points by enabling breakpoint of line by mouse click. But if I write :

```
b main
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x401378.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x401378: file src/test.cpp, line 18.
```

to the eclipse console breakpoint,break point working.

Does anyone has any idea about that? Why UI breakpoint is not working .

Secondly lets say I add break point to line 12.(it happens very often any point in program 12 is just a example) When I "continue", I am not being able to execute "next","step" or view variables but if I put one more break point to one line after line 13 and "continue" everything is back normal again. I am again being able to use "next","step" etc... 
This is disturbing me because I need to add unnecessary break points for this situation.

Any help will be appriaciated about those two problems related with remote debugging with eclipse UI.